# remove RelativeLayout from javacode

Tags: android, json

i have a probleme taht i use webservices , and i want that when i don't have anything from this json web services to remove the relativelayout that i made in my code , this is my layout who had 3relative layouts :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2F2F2" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtview/prog_match"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/program"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtview/Last_Match"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+txtview/prog_match"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt_last_match"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtview/Next_Match"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+txtview/Last_Match"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt_next_match"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/match"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+txtview/Last_Match"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+txtviews/txt_date"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/next_date"
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+txtviews/txt_vs_match"
        android:layout_below="@+txtviews/txt_vs_next_match"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/next_match"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+txtviews/txt_date"
        android:layout_below="@+txtview/Next_Match"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/next_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+txtviews/txt_next_date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+txtviews/txt_time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/txt_next_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+txtviews/txt_next_date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+txtviews/txt_score"
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+txtviews/txt_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+txtviews/txt_vs_match"
        android:layout_below="@+txtviews/txt_vs_match"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+txtviews/txt_time"
         android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+txtviews/txt_date"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+txtviews/txt_date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my code sometimes when i have get(0) or get(1) the application crash so i want that when i don't have anything to remove one of the relativeLayout :

```
private void prog() {

            programs = JSONParser.parseProgram(savedData);



                txt1.setText(programs.get(1).getTitle());
                txt2.setText(programs.get(0).getTitle());
                txt3.setText(programs.get(1).getScore());
                txt4.setText(programs.get(0).getScore());
                txt5.setText(programs.get(1).getMatchdate());
                txt6.setText(programs.get(0).getMatchdate());
                txt7.setText(programs.get(1).getTime());
                txt8.setText(programs.get(0).getTime());
```

and this is my json parser :

```
public static MonProg ProgramParser(JSONObject jsonProgram) {

        Program program = new Program();



        try {


                program.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(jsonProgram.getString("title")).toString());
                program.setReport(jsonProgram.getString("report").toString());
                program.setScore(jsonProgram.getString("score").toString());
                program.setTime(jsonProgram.getString("start_time").toString());
                program.setMatchdate(jsonProgram.getString("date").toString());

            return program;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove element with view with:

```
ViewGroup myViewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewToRemove.getParent();
myViewGroup.removeView(viewToRemove);
```

But I supposes that you cannot remove root view in this way. So either remove everything inside, ore wrap RelativeLayout in 1 more container, give it id, and then use above function. viewToRemove should point id of your RelativeLayout.

Or simply:

```
view.setVisiblility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: so i should give an id to my relativeLayout then remove it when i have null from web services ?

Comment: simplier if you give id and perform setVisiblility(View.GONE) on it. Otherwise you have to give id and wrap in one more container.

Comment: yes i did it , but i don't know how to use it when i  don't have anything from webservices , sorry i'm ust begginer that's why , i will use it on parser or main or what and how and sorry ,

Comment: so you don't know where to write if (); else :)